# Is it possible to create sticky note "Start here for SEO newbies?"

Tags: discussion

Not sure if this is the right place to post this type of question. I'm hoping a moderator will move it to the right group, if not.

Webmasters obviously receives lots of queries that have been already answered. I suspect that many of the posters simply came to the site and don't know where to start or what term to search for. We know a lot of users simply don't know where to start or think that their question has never been asked before. As as a result, they just post questions, without looking under Hot or previous posts.

So, is it possible/practical to create a sticky post that says "New to SEO or this site? Start here". In the sticky include the major topics and links to those articles that are deemed the best answers.

Topics might include:

```
Keywords stuffing
Sitemap paradox
Etc
```

I'm sure there's an argument for "Users don't read the start here" any more than they look for previous answers. But if we could direct users who are new to SEO to a single post that contained the fundamental topics, would that be of value?

Comment: How about writing a canonical, FAQ-like Q&A and if it's really good, figure out whether to sticky it?

Answer (score 2):

There's a little section in the [on-topic page](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) that covers catch-all questions.

It's a bit tucked away if you ask me, and it doesn't include some of the posts you would expect, like your [Sitemap paradox](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox) example. It also seems that askers are (mis?)using the [catch-all](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/catch-all) tag for questions about catch-all email.

As for promoting questions like this to a more visible sticky on Webmasters SE, my opinion is that the kind of user who doesn't read this "on-topic" page is the same kind of user who probably wouldn't bother reading sticky questions either, I think, so it could make sense to just curate the catch-all tag to include more common questions.

Personally I find that the current close-vote system works rather well (usually my one close vote to kick it into the queue, then a mod hammer), since it's not like we're overwhelmed here with tripe questions every 3.5 seconds like on SO.

But that's all just my opinion. I like the idea, in theory!